# Negative singular value using LAPACK svd

Tags: r

I have a 399 x 399 matrix for which the R svd() function (using LAPACK) gives me a negative singular value! This is not supposed to happen -- has anyone seen this before? It does not happen if I use the LINPACK option, so I guess this is a bug in the LAPACK svd.

```
ganymede: R --vanilla

R version 2.15.1 (2012-06-22) -- "Roasted Marshmallows"
Copyright (C) 2012 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
ISBN 3-900051-07-0
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin9.8.0/x86_64 (64-bit)

R is free software, etc ...

> load('A.dat')
> ls()
[1] "A"
> dim(A)
[1] 399 399
> 
> L1 <- svd(A)
> any( L1$d < 0 )
[1] TRUE
> L1$d[1:4]
[1] 80.18833 68.93905 61.62659 57.62883
> L1$d[396:399]
[1]  3.777844e-15  3.582460e-15  3.175665e-15 -6.512578e+00
> 
> L2 <- svd(A,LINPACK=TRUE)
> any( L2$d < 0 )
[1] FALSE
> L2$d[1:4]
[1] 80.18833 68.93905 61.62659 57.62883
> L2$d[396:399]
[1] 8.565532e-32 3.254162e-32 3.484425e-47 5.411232e-48
>
```

Comment: Does [this bug report](https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla3/show_bug.cgi?id=14962) apply to your problem?

Comment: I think it does. The suggested fix is to link against LAPACK 3.4.1 rather than the default 3.1.1. I'll have to give that a try. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Roland: care to add that as an answer, assuming it's the solution to Robert's problem?

Answer (score 0):

Per [this bug report](https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla3/show_bug.cgi?id=14962) the problem can most likely be fixed by relinking against LAPACK 3.4.1. Upgrading the generic version 3.1.1 seems to be non-trivial and the procedure depends on the OS.